# Pure CSS/3 Solution to non-square thumbnails in a square area

Tags: css

Given a non-square image, I'd like to scale this to fit a 200px x 200px box:

- Maintaining aspect ratio
- Handling both portrait and landscape
- Chopping only in one dimension
- Using purely CSS / CSS3
- Scaling images smaller than 200px up
- Scaling images larger than 200px down

Stated with an image:

[image]

Is it possible?

Comment: For each image, do you know whether it's landscape or portrait? In other words, can you accept a non-CSS way of discovering which dimension is longest?

Comment: No, orientation is unknown, and JS cannot be used.  Unless it's impossible otherwise.

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but it's impossible otherwise.

Comment: @Yisela this would violate the third requirement

Comment: This is much easier than you think. Writing up an answer. FYI, no JS required.

Comment: @NicholasHazel waiting eagerly :)

Comment: What would the markup be like?

Comment: @Terry an img inside of a div

Comment: @RobVious Probably not likely that a pure-CSS3 solution would work, because of the following requirements: (1) scaling up AND down (so ruling out the use of min/max widths) and (2) not using JS (where assigning image as background-image of parent div or detecting image orientation is possible with JS)

Comment: @RobVious I'm making it. Just centering it for you. It's all built to constrain it, just positioning. One moment sir.

Comment: It would be easier if not "chopping from one direction" -- `background-size:cover` could be sufficient.

Comment: @Passerby - one dimension*  I don't care if it's one or two directions (left and right or top and bottom is ok)

Comment: @RobVious http://jsfiddle.net/434nU/ ?

Comment: Using a script OK? I have everything working, much like @passerby (lil expanded), but getting it to downsize may require a script.

Comment: There's a good article on this here: http://css-tricks.com/crop-top/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a html/css only solution that does everything you need, including scaling downward.

```
<div class='square-image'></div>

.square-image {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(your/image.jpg);
}
```

The only (minor) downside is that you have to use a background image instead of a img tag. To do this easily (thanks to RobVious) you can just apply the background image inline. So your html might look like this:

```
<div style="background-image: url(your/image1.jpg)" class="square-image"></div>
<div style="background-image: url(your/image2.jpg)" class="square-image"></div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, scaling down is a requirement.  Totally forgot to add that.

Comment: Hmm, then I'll need to do some testing

Comment: "so you'll need a different css class for each image" - I *think* I can just apply the background-image property in-line using knockoutJS, so every image can be the same class...

Comment: The problem with this is it aligns the `bg` at the `0, 0` coordinates, instead of actually shifting it left/right/up/down to show the center of the image.

Comment: The original question clearly shows images that are not centered. Centered was not a requirement, however, it could be done. Let me think.

Comment: Centering is not a requirement, but if you know how it can be done, I'm sure future users would find it useful.  This is gold...

Comment: Oh, I thought that was the goal. Hit the center of the img, and only crop horizontal OR vertical. Am I wasting my time? Been writing this crap for 25 minutes now bouncing back and forth for what I'm supposed to do haha.

Comment: @NicholasHazel I didn't make any mention of centering, but yes, horizontal OR vertical was a requirement.  I'd hate for you to spend more time on your solution as I think this does the trick...  thanks so much for the help everyone.

Comment: I could have posted that about 30 minutes ago haha. I'm going to keep playing, since I'm so far :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible, but only if you know beforehand whether the image is landscape or portrait. HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="photo.jpg">
</div>
```

Then, using JS or some server-side magic (yes I know this violates a requirement; there's no other way), add a class to the `<img>` that's either `landscape` or `portrait`. Now, CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 200px; height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.landscape {
    height: 100%;
}

.portrait {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Bear in mind that such things are usually done server-side for a good reason: so the browser doesn't need to download a big image only to display just part of it. You mentioned mobile devices (somewhere, in a comment maybe) when complaining about JS, but that impact is negligible compared to the extra bandwidth.

I suppose you could use this JS (off the top of my head) (must be called after DOM ready):

```
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll(".container img");
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    var img = imgs[0];
    if (img.width > img.height) img.classList.add('landscape');
    else if (img.width < img.height) img.classList.add('portrait');
}
```

To avoid a flicker, you could hide the images with `display: none` and then unhide in the JS after the classes have been applied.

It is not a big performance hit at all. It uses the browser's native CSS selection engine, which is almost as fast as `getElementById`. There is no width/height calculation going on here; the browser has already calculated that by the time the document is ready. There is room for micro-optimization though:

- Use a more efficient for-loop construct (how, I'm not sure)
- Get rid of the `else if` clause and stick in an `else`: it'll make the JS faster but the CSS less efficient, an OK trade-off.
- Use `className` instead of `classList`. Again, going into micro-opt territory.

Comment: `.container img{min-width:200px; min-height:200px;}`

Comment: This is the cleanest solution I can think of... my only concern is that images will look glitchy as the page renders, and the performance impact of applying this to 100+ thumbnails...

Comment: Is it possible to check the image orientation in the server side? That way you avoid the "glitchy" effect of javascript.

Comment: @azeós I can't.. images are hosted on an external CDN

Comment: @RobVious True, that could be a problem. You could have the images `display: none` by default, then cancel out the style in the JS.

Comment: I believe add landscape/portrait classes this way is not good, because what if images contain human faces and different is dimensions, like sometimes height is  bigger and sometime width.

Comment: @RobVious And as for your performance concern: there is very little impact. The CSS selector engine is very fast and runs only once. No width/height calculation takes place; the browser has already done that. You could micro-optimize by using a better loop (maybe `for (var i = imgs.length; i--;)`) and/or by converting the `else if` into an `else` but... I wouldn't bother.

Comment: Bandwidth isn't a huge concern because the images will already be resized down to reasonable sizes (by the CDN - imgur).  I think this solution is great if CSS3 is not an option... but if CSS3 is ok, the other answer seems best.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, using a little JS wouldn't kill. My solution leverages on the `background-size: cover` property, and uses jQuery (or you can use raw JS) to hide the child `<img>` and set the parent's background to the child image's source attribute.

CSS:

```
div {
    background-size: cover;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('div').each(function(){
        $(this)
        .find('img')
            .hide()
            .end()
        .css({
            'background-image': 'url('+$(this).find('img').attr('src')+')'
        });
    });
});
```

Here's a proof-of-concept demo: [<kbd>jsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/MZPbH/)

Comment: "a little JS" x 100 on mobile devices COULD very well kill UX

Comment: @RobVious The JS isn't the problem if done right (see my answer). The jQuery is what does you in.

Comment: @rvighne If you looked closely, there's something in parentheses in my answer: 'or you can use raw JS'